# Query to find a critical situation in Greenplum database(4.3.12) which has postgres version 8.2.15

Tags: select, plpgsql, greenplum, blockingqueue

Need a SELECT query that can find the users,procpids along with query statements runs by them with the waiting_state when a particular table is accessed in their respective queries which as a result leads to the concept of blocking table and waiting table.

Thanks.

Comment: That is just pg_locks.  http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/5100/ref_guide/system_catalogs/pg_locks.html

Comment: Can I get a query? It will be very helpful.

Comment: Which GP version are you using?

Comment: @AnuraagVeerapaneni 4.3.12

Comment: check out below link. You will find all the useful queries

https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/Script---Database-Locks

Comment: @AnuraagVeerapaneni Or may be a function?

Comment: you can place your desired query in a function and query it

Comment: @AnuraagVeerapaneni Yes, actually I needed that query itself.